# Reliability of C# SmtpClient email code (when images are involved)

Tags: c#, email, graphics, html-email, smtpclient

I have, so far as I know, a piece of relatively vanilla SMTP Client code in my C# Dot Net 4.0 web application.  This has been working fine for sometime now, cranking out text messages with minimal HTML formatting.  *(If memory serves, it was based on this: http://blog.jdconley.com/2009/01/fire-and-forget-email-webservices-and.html)*

Now the powers that be want to add graphics.  The details have yet to be finalized but for the moment I am assuming that they would want to use graphic images either by themselves or as background for some HTML construct.

Frankly I am not an email expert.  After a bit of hacking I managed to get this to work, sort of. (This hack is based on this: *http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/how-to-send-an-email-using-c-net-with-complete-features/*   I also added an AlternativeView list to the MessageInfo object for processing in the main mail routine. The logo image itself is a part of the project, sitting in the root.)

I have several worries here.
**First and foremost, how generic is this?  Is this the best approach?**  How many types of mail server will be able to receive and properly display this?

In my testing, this succeeds when I send it to myself in Outlook over the company server.  This message does not arrive when I try to send it to my personal accounts at Yahoo or Gmail.  *(Yes, I've checked the spam buckets.)*

Suggestions?

```
MessageInfo mi = new MessageInfo();
MessageStatusInfo msi = new MessageStatusInfo();
EmailAgent ea = new EmailAgent();         
ea.minfoDefaultCommunicationSettings = new DefaultCommunicationSettingsInfo();
mi.EmailToAddresses.Add("AnAddress@MyCompany.com");            
mi.EmailFrom = "Someone@MyCompany.com";
mi.EmailSubject = "Email Test";
mi.IsBodyHtml = true;
mi.SMTPServer = "My Company's Email Server";
string str = "<html><body><table border='5'><tr><td><img src=\"cid:image1\"></td></tr></table></body></html>";
AlternateView av = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
LinkedResource lr = new LinkedResource(Server.MapPath("logo.jpg"), MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
lr.ContentId = "image1";
av.LinkedResources.Add(lr);
mi.avc.Add(av);            
msi = ea.SendMail(mi);
```

Comment: does putting a try/catch block around msi = ea.SendMail(mi); generate any error for emails outside the company?

Comment: None apparently.  I added both my company and yahoo addresses to the EmailToAddresses collection and the return said the message had been sent successfully.  I got it in my company box as usual but nothing in Yahoo.  I then sent the message to my Yahoo address alone,  Same success message but still nothing in my Yahoo account.  I suppose there could be some freak delay in getting out of the company and if it shows up in a few hours I'll post here, but at this time,  I doubt it.

Comment: Since you are using EmailAgent instead of SmtpClient I notice you are not using anything other than the default Queue. Have a look at  http://www.aspemail.com/net_manual_04.html particularly section 4.1 "Message Queuing: Overview "

Comment: Pardon my inexperience.  I will read that reference but I don't understand your statement 'EmailAgent instead of SmtpClient.'  The ea.SendMail method in turn calls a System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient object.

Comment: EmailAgent allows for more extensive message queuing, bouncing,  relaying etc. SmtpClient is a more often used subset. Either can work.

Comment: I think we're trying to keep this as simple as possible.